# How to install psycopg2 on Python 3.9 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, psycopg2

I have been trying to install psycopg2 (`pip install psycopg2`), but I keep getting this error.

I have also tried with: `pip install psycopg2-binary` but I'm getting the **same error**.

Here is the error message:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\viktor\pycharmprojects\wemport\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Viktor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-015ceiei\\psycop
g2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Viktor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-015ceiei\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'
"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl'
         cwd: C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-015ceiei\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3shb13sl\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to fix that?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1160) "Python 3.9 is not supported yet. Packages have not been released.", "Appveyor doesn't support Python 3.9 yet".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will install prebuilt binaries for windows. It's worked for me on 3.9. You can uninstall pipwin after install psycopg2.

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install psycopg2
```

*Optional after psycopg2 installed:*

```
pip uninstall pipwin
```

Answer (score -2):

> if u use linux

You need to make sure that you install wheel model
and Try that
`sudo ./venv/bin/python -m pip install wheel`

after that install psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary

`sudo ./venv/bin/python -m pip install psycopg2`

`sudo ./venv/bin/python -m pip install psycopg-binary`